# TComboBoxEx with VCL-Styles: Borders flicker

Tags: delphi, combobox, vcl-styles

I`m using Delphi XE3. When using the custom styles (e.g. Carbon) that are available since Delphi XE2, there is a visible white flickering when moving the mouse over the borders of the TComboBoxEx control (MouseExit/Enter).

Steps to reproduce: Create a new VCL Forms app, drop a TComboBoxEx on the form, select e.g. Carbon in project options --> Application\Appearance and start the application

Is this a known problem/bug and is any solution known?

Thank you

Comment: Which steps must be follow to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @RRUZ: Create a new VCL Forms app, drop a TComboBoxEx on the form, select e.g. Carbon in project options --> Application\Appearance and start the application

Comment: I might just add that the color that flickers when you move the mouse over border is the color assigned to the control. This is most likely a bug in the TComboBoxExStyleHook.

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce this issue I'm using Delphi XE3 17.0.4625.53395 in Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This Border flicker issue is not the product of using Delphi VCL Styles.**

(The same problem can be observed without using VCL styles)

The culprit here is the [Desktop Window Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is an essential part of 
Windows Visual Styles and Themes.

The reason why you are seeing this issue and others may not, is because you have at some point changed the default Windows Theme (aero theme) or you've changed a specific Visual effect property of your selected theme.

You perhaps also have intentionally or unintentionally disabled the Desktop Window Manager since it runs as a Windows service.

To be more exact, the issue is resolved if you enable the **Desktop composition** feature. 

This feature is only available in **Aero** themes(default) but not in *Basic* or *Classic*, tho sometimes it can appear to be available even when it is not.

`Control Panel --> System --> Advanced System Settings --> Advanced --> Performance Settings --> Visual Effects`

[image]

> When desktop composition is enabled, individual windows no longer draw
>   directly to the screen or primary display device as they did in
>   previous versions of Windows. Instead, their drawing is redirected to
>   off-screen surfaces in video memory, which are then rendered into a
>   desktop image and presented on the display.

As you might have guessed, the functionality of this function is to basically act as a Buffer
 which in a very neat way explains the border flickering when this option is turned off.

### Important Fact

Desktop composition feature can only be enabled if your current theme is an Aero theme and using [Windows Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).(It is by default enabled for every Aero Theme)

Visual Styles are enabled by default in Aero Themes, you can check that it is enabled by making sure that the `Use Visual Styles on Windows` feature is enabled in the Performance Settings. When the Classic or Basic Themes are in effect the desktop composition feature is never in play and cannot be enabled. (Classic theme has been deprecated since Windows 8)

Sometimes in Windows 7, the Desktop composition feature can show itself in the Performance Options even when using a Basic or Classic Theme but do not be fooled, this is an internal bug.

Steps to reproduce this bug :

1. Start With default Windows Aero Theme
2. Go into Performance Settings as described above
3. Uncheck the Desktop composition from the list
4. Mouse over the border of TComboBoxEx, it should now be flickering as
   you enter/leave.

---

**But what happens if I uncheck `Use Visual Styles on Windows` checkbox? Why does this solve the flickering issue?**

This will cause the Desktop Window Manager(DWM) to disable themes all together for all Windows Controls. What this means is that controls will be drawn using an older rendering style as oppose to using the newer Aero rendering style.

You can turn off Visual Styles for individual controls without turning it off globally with the following method `SetWindowTheme(Handle, nil, nil)`

This is also why the flickering issue for TComboBoxEx border is resolved when Visual Styles are disabled. 
It's also worth mentioning that since Windows 8 you cannot disable Visual Styles anymore because as I said the Classic theme is deprecated.

---

Regarding the solution, I don't think you've got much of a choice really. Given how much freedom is left to the user when it comes to modifying the visual effects of *Windows themes*, this sort of thing is bound to happen. At least you can be certain that this issue does not happen on the default Windows Theme.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! It looks promising. I couldn't verify it so far, but might find some time tomorrow.

Comment: Cheers. I use VCL Styles a lot and because I myself use a very customized Windows Theme, I very often encounter such issues and I can say that it extends to a lot more windows native controls. Just a very sad side effect unfortunatelly of sacrificing visual appearance for performance.

Comment: @torno, I've added some more important info, check the important info paragraph.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but for me it`s the option "Use visual styles for windows and control" (don't know if it`s the exact english term because I`m using a german system). If it`s disabled, all other options can be enabled and the bug is still gone. just enabled this one --> the bug appears again. do you have an idea why there is a difference on my system?

Comment: @torno, I've wrote about the `Use Visual Styles` briefly in my Important Info paragraph but let me explain what this does exactly, when you disable this feature you basically disable theming all together which makes the Desktop Window Manager force an older control rendering style as oppose the rendering style that is used in Aero. This is why your bug disappears when you uncheck the `Use visual Styles`, because it switches to a different render style. However, like I said in my answer, if you do use an Aero theme, then the solution is to enable `Desktop composition`.

Comment: @torno, I have updated my answer to explain the `Use Visual Styles` option.

Comment: sorry, you are right - it works when enabling the "desktop composition" feature. do you maybe know if this option is enabled or disabled by default when using the aero style? thanks again

Comment: the flickering still appears some times but this can be optimized by setting the themed color as color: Color := StyleServices.GetStyleColor(scComboBox) in e.g. CreateWnd

Comment: @torno, desktop composition is enabled by default for every Aero theme style. Cheers.